# Initializing Firebase for a React or React Native app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

When adding Firebase to a React (regular or native) app. What is a better practice:

- To use `componentDidMount` inside the component (for example `App.js`)?

  ```
  componentDidMount () {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "YOUR-API-KEY",
      authDomain: "YOUR-PROJECT.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://YOUR-PROJECT.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "YOUR-PROJECT",
      storageBucket: "YOUR-PROJECT.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "000000000000"
    })    
  }
  ```

or

- To create a `firebaseConfig` constant and then call `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` outside of the component?

  ```
   const firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "YOUR-API-KEY",
     authDomain: "YOUR-PROJECT.firebaseapp.com",
     databaseURL: "https://YOUR-PROJECT.firebaseio.com",
     projectId: "YOUR-PROJECT",
     storageBucket: "YOUR-PROJECT.appspot.com",
     messagingSenderId: "000000000000"
   }

   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  ```

Also, is there a performance implications by using any of the mentioned approaches?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be fine either way, like most things in React, it's a preference.
I can't see there being any difference in performance depending on which way you called that same function.

EDIT: Actually, there will be a difference. You will be reconfiguring each time your component mounts instead of just once.